# Invert system of Trigonometric Equations

Tags: trigonometry, systems-of-equations

I have a series of three equations that transform three angles of a system (J1, J2, J3), into three spatial x, y, z coordinates as follows:

x = A + B cos(J3) + C sin(J2) cos (J1)

y = A + B cos(J3) + C sin (J2) sin (J1)

z = C (cos(J2) - 1) - B sin (J3)

Here A, B and C are numerical constants that I know the value of. What I want is to be able to invert the problem, namely find expressions to calculate the values of J1 to J3 given a set of coordinates (with the angles within the range -180 to 180, where a solution exists). I am struggling a bit with this. Is this possible and if so how can I go about it. Thank you in advance for any help or hints.